# Confirm navigation dialog appears after cancelling edit by reloading post

Tags: bug, edits, alerts

If a post is updated while you're editing, a notification will appear allowing you to reload the post (and cancel your own edits). However, it appears the page still *thinks* you have pending edits. If you attempt to navigate away from the page, a confirmation dialog will ask you if you are sure you want to leave.

Here's what it looks like in Chrome:

[image: alert dialog]

I've confirmed this on SO and MSO.

**Proposed solution:** When you reload a post that you were editing, clear the `onbeforeunload` event.